# Is there a way to use "ShouldSerialize[PropertyName]" on a Property of a Property?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, serialization, windows-forms-designer

The problem i am facing is that when i have a class with a property with a default value like this:

```
public class Border {
    public Border() {
        InitializeAdornment();
    }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Visible {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void InitializeAdornment() {
        Visible = true;
        // Some initialization code here that don't do anything with the property...
    }
}
```

And then use it as a property of a UserControl with `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` attribute on it, like this:

```
public class Label : HitAbleControl, IText, IBorder {
    public Label() {
        InitializeAdornments();
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Border Border {
        get {
            return __border;
        }
        set {
            __border = value;
        }
    }

    private Border __border;

    private void InitializeAdornments() {
        Border = new Border {
            Visible = false
        };
        // Some initialization code here that don't do anything with the property...
    }
}
```

If I set the `label1.Border.Visible = true` using the Visual Studio Designer, it does not get serialized, but it should as the default value in this case should be false and not true.

I know that I could change the `Border` class to always serialize, or to check if the default value should be true or false, but I would like to know if there are something like a `ShouldSerialize[PropertyName]` to a property of a property or another workaround to this serialization issue, without changing the serializer.

I searched for hours trying to solve this issue without appealing to a `CodeDomSerializer`, or at least understand why the visual studio designer don't serialize this.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you really need `Border` property to be publicly settable?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev In my original code, the Label class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, for simplicity i changed it to have only the backing field to post here

Comment: INPC is not essential, my question was should it be settable from outside. Normally when you have class instances, you set them internally inside a constructor, and let only their properties be settable from outside. I'm asking because it's essential.

Comment: The user should be able to set it to another Border instance (i.e. from another UI theme) without having to copy each Border property value, but anyway, i tried to serialize it without the setter and had no success. VS keeps considering it have the default value on Visible

Comment: Of course you can't. My previous questions were only to figure out how to proceed. Shortly, we need somehow to provide the defaults to the `Border` class from outside, there is simple no other way.

Comment: Did you try using Visible instead of Content? Content wouldn't really do anything for a bool. Content is to serialize the properties of properties, I believe. Try DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible and see if that helps.

Comment: @Nikki9696 In this case, `Content` is on the `Border` property, not the `bool Visible`, so the `bool` is intended to be serialized as it is a property of the property with `Content` attribute. With `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible` the designer will always create another instance of the Border class, which is already being created on the `InitializeAdornments()` called in the constructor of the `Label` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first state that there is no `ShouldSerialize[PropertyName]` or other standard mechanism for controlling the behavior of the nested object property.

What you are asking for can be done, but requires some additional state inside the contained class. It could have been simpler if you didn't provide a public setter, so you can pass some sort of a owner interface or something to be called from the `Border` class. Since this seems to not be an option, then it requires some additional work as cloning the passed value inside the setter.

The whole point is to have a default value as class property, rather than static constant. Note that it doesn't matter if you set the value via designer or code, the serializer uses the `DefaultValueAttribute` to determine if the value needs to be serialized or not. Btw, the simplest approach could be to remove that attribute, add a `bool` method called `ShouldSerializeVisible` and return always `true`. Here is a more advanced implementation:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Border
{
    public Border()
    {
        InitializeAdornment();
    }

    public Border Clone() { return (Border)MemberwiseClone(); }

    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    private bool ShouldSerializeVisible() { return Visible != DefaultVisible; }
    private void ResetVisible() { Visible = DefaultVisible; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public bool DefaultVisible { get; set; }

    private void InitializeAdornment()
    {
        Visible = DefaultVisible = true;
        // Some initialization code here that don't do anything with the property...
    }
}
```

Note the `DefaultValueAttribute` removed and replaced with private `ShouldSerialize[PropertyName]` and `Reset[PropertyName]` methods plus `DefaultVisible` instance member.

The property inside your `Label` class will be:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public Border Border
{
    get { return __border; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            value = value.Clone();
            value.DefaultVisible = false;
        }
        __border = value;
    }
}
```

The drawback is that the passed `Border` instance must be cloned inside the setter.

Comment: IMO, the drawback of the designer always serializing the property is more acceptable than the drawback of cloning the instance and having another property to tell the default value to consider, so I ended up using a `private bool ShouldSerializeVisible() => true;`.
My little hope was some way to tell the designer in a declarative manner, but as you stated, there isn't. So I will mark as answer, as you stated the only possible ways.
Thank you for the help!